# redis-py and hgetall behavior

Tags: python-3.x, redis, redis-py

I played around with flask microframework, and wanted to cache some stats in redis. Let's say I have this dict:

```
mydict = {}
mydict["test"] = "test11"
```

I saved it to redis with

```
redis.hmset("test:key", mydict)
```

However after restore

```
stored = redis.hgetall("test:key")
print(str(stored))
```

I see weird `{b'test': b'test11'}` so `stored.get("test")` gives me None

`mydict` str method result looks fine `{'test': 'test11'}`. So, why this binary marker added to restored data? I also checked in redis-cli and don't see explicit b markers there. Something wrong with hgetall?

Comment: If someone interested, here is answer from developer: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/463#issuecomment-41229918

Answer (score 31):

> This is the intended behavior. By default, strings coming out of Redis
>   don't get decoded. You have a couple options:
>
> - Decode the data yourself.
> - Create a client instance with the `decode_responses` argument, e.g., `StrictRedis(decode_responses=True)`. This will decode all strings
>     that come from Redis based on the `charset` argument (which defaults
>     to utf-8). Only do this is you're sure every response from Redis has
>     string data that you want decoded to utf-8. If you're using the same
>     client instance to get binary data such as a pickled object, you
>     shouldn't use this option. In that case, I'd suggest using a separate
>     client instance for the binary data.

Source: https://github.com/andymccurdy/redis-py/issues/463#issuecomment-41229918

Comment: This argument is undocumented and it doesn't seems to work:
`python3`

`>>> import redis`
`>>> POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)`
`>>> datastore = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=POOL, decode_responses=True)`
`>>> mydict = {}`
`>>> mydict["test"] = "test11"`
`>>> datastore.hmset("test:key", mydict)`
`True`
`>>> stored = datastore.hgetall("test:key")`
`>>> stored`
`{b'test': b'test11'}`

Answer (score 11):

```
POOL = redis.ConnectionPool(host='localhost', **decode_responses=True**, port=6379, db=0)
datastore = redis.StrictRedis(connection_pool=POOL)
```

**if you use the ConnectionPool, you should move the decode_responses=True to the constructor of ConnectionPool.**

Answer (score 8):

Here's a simple routine to perform the byte decoding for the redis dict returned by HGETALL

```
def decode_redis(src):
    if isinstance(src, list):
        rv = list()
        for key in src:
            rv.append(decode_redis(key))
        return rv
    elif isinstance(src, dict):
        rv = dict()
        for key in src:
            rv[key.decode()] = decode_redis(src[key])
        return rv
    elif isinstance(src, bytes):
        return src.decode()
    else:
        raise Exception("type not handled: " +type(src))
```

... and to use, just pass it the redis dict  ...

```
obj = decode_redis(redis_connection.hgetall(key))
```

Comment: Well thank you pal, but this question is 5.5 years old.

Comment: @Tommi, understood, but can still be helpful to others with same problem